# Composer post-install-cmd is failing with multiple commands in travis-ci

Tags: wordpress, npm, gruntjs, composer-php, travis-ci

I'm learning building a project for easy collaboration and with continuous integration. So I created a [branch](https://github.com/nanodesigns/nanosupport/tree/testing) of my WordPress Plugin.

I made the `composer.json` with:

```
"scripts": {
    "post-install-cmd": ["npm install", "grunt"],
    "pre-archive-cmd": "composer install"
}
```

It's doing nice in my local install on a Windows machine, and after running `npm install` being loaded with all its dependencies it then can run `grunt`. But using the Travis CI it's failing saying:

> Script npm install && grunt handling the post-install-cmd event returned with error code 3
>   The command "composer install" failed and exited with 3 during .

So, I changed my command to [this](https://github.com/nanodesigns/nanosupport/commit/f180d5c6f56677f507bec9541d16a13025c5ef67): `"npm install && grunt"` and failed too.

Then I passed with a [single command](https://github.com/nanodesigns/nanosupport/blob/testing/composer.json#L58): `"npm install"` in `post-install-cmd`.

What am I doing wrong here? Why is the multiple command doing fine in local environment, but cannot in Travis CI? And what exactly the error code 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to tell travis to install npm & grunt before you can use it.

```
before_script:
- npm install -g grunt-cli
- npm install
```

As i see here https://github.com/nanodesigns/nanosupport/blob/testing/.travis.yml
its missing in your travis file.

**Update:**
You also need to specify the node version, either with the engines directive in package.json:

```
{ "engines" : { "node" : ">=4" } }
```

or via ENV vars

```
env:
  - TRAVIS_NODE_VERSION="4"
```

Comment: +1 for the nice suggestion. I missed that. But somehow the concatenation of `grunt` command is still struggling passing Travis-CI. [Build 1](https://travis-ci.org/nanodesigns/nanosupport/builds/180056833) with `["npm install","grunt"]` and [Build 2](https://travis-ci.org/nanodesigns/nanosupport/builds/180057824) with `"npm install && grunt"` both failed passing the`post-install-cmd` declaration in `Composer.json`

Comment: npm install is already executed in before_script, try only grunt in post-install-cmd

Comment: but the error happens in postcss: "Warning: Promise is not defined", probably a too old node version is used

Comment: The problem is not with `post-install-cmd` declaration. Thanks for your answer. It's coming from `postcss`, you are right. Let me dig in. I tried mentioning the node version in `packages.json` as you suggested, but still facing the broken build. Anyway, thanks for your response. I accepted your answer as it was to-the-point to the `post-install-cmd`-specific question.

Comment: What I found till now that, syntax for `post-install-cmd` is right with array `["npm install","grunt"]`. Whether it's correct or not I can confirm after a successful build inshALLAH.